# List View with array adapter custom view layout. Requires Resource ID

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am currently trying to populate a ListView inside a fragment from a SQL Query. The ListView has a Custom List View called list_order_layout_order_progress. It crashes once I get to the specific fragment.

Any help will greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The On create View where i declare the listview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabe_fragment_order_progress, container, false);
    OrderNumber = getArguments().getInt("OrderNoFinal");
    ProductID = getArguments().getInt("ProductID");
    ProductionID = getArguments().getInt("ProductionID");

    lblOrderNo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtProgOrderNo);
    lblProduct = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtProgProduct);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();

    GetProductName();
    PopulateOrderProgressList();


    return rootView;
}
```

The code where i set the array adapter

```
public void PopulateOrderProgressList(){

    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();

    try {

        String sql = "exec sp_Get_Production_Tasks\n@Production_ID  = " + ProductionID + ",@Product_ID  = " + ProductID;
        final ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(rs.getString("Task_Name"));
        }

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_layout_orderprogress , list));

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The Layout that contains the ListView that is a fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
tools:context="layout.OrderProgress">

    <TextView
        android:text="Order:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtProgOrderNo"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/ltxtProduct" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtProgProduct" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Start"
                        android:textColor="#FF4081"
                        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView31" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FF4081"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Finish"
                        android:id="@+id/textView32" />

            </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Update"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The Custom Layout View for the ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox5" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView30"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

The Error message that shows when it crashes:

```
08-25 21:38:12.731 25022-25022/dura_art.bigbyte E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: dura_art.bigbyte, PID: 25022
                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
                                                                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1560)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1192)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1841)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                at android.app.Activi
```

Comment: Just so you are aware, it is actually not recommended to connect Android to JDBC

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter only knows how to handle a list of TextViews. You are wanting to use a list of custom views, thus you'll have to make a custom ArrayAdapter. This can be done by creating a subclass that inherits ArrayAdapter.

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) for ArrayAdapter:
*"By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView."*

Here's the tutorial I followed doing my first custom ArrayAdapter: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter